# Ubuntu linux 16.04 LTS localhost/phpmyadmin empty

Tags: 16.04, lamp

I've followed the procedures on installing LAMP on ubuntu linux 16.04 LTS but when i tried to go `localhost/phpmyadmin` it says that

```
"Not Found
The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80"
```

How To fix this kind of error?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your apache2.conf to make phpMyAdmin work. For more detail  Please read [this section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Phpmyadmin%20and%20mysql-admin) in Ubuntu wiki.

open a termianl and run

```
gksu gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add the following line to the end of the file.

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then restart apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

`

Comment: what i had is still the same problem empty error 404

Comment: try running these commands one at a time `sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`  ; `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin`  ;  `sudo service apache2 restart`   ; now visit  localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: **Note** - don't include semi-colons, these are only to separate the commands.

Comment: still same empty localhost/phpmyadmin/  displays empty page

Comment: I did also follow this procedure https://websetnet.com/install-lamp-stack-ubuntu-1604-linux-apache-mysql-php/  still same phpmyadmin empty page. but if localhost apache2 is good it displays something. but localhost/phpmyadmin = empty page

Comment: problem solve the solution is just this one sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext; sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution that worked for me

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin
```

Then select Apache 2 for the webserver you wish to configure.

[HOW TO FIX ""The requested URL /phpMyAdmin was not found on this server.""](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-fix-the-requested-url-phpmyadmin-was-not-found-on-this-server-796610/)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [a comment by Sinscary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771441/ubuntu-linux-16-04-lts-localhost-phpmyadmin-empty/1028126#comment1152635_771444), I tried this and it worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: please fix formatting ...